# SSRS Report in MVC APP (web form page) and ViewState

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am not able to use the SSRS report viewer in a web form page within a MVC application.  It all works great, but when the control goes to render I always get the error within the control:

ASP.NET ViewState has been disabled. The Report Viewer control requires that ViewState be enabled.

I set EnableViewState to true on the control and at the @Page directive, as well as in the code-behind... but no avail.  So obviously that's not the case, but I'm unsure how to resolve, since I see other user's have had success...

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out; I was missing the  definition around the report viewer :-;

Found this out by reading: http://forums.asp.net/t/994250.aspx (further down the thread).